# Why could two different unnamed namespace co-exist in one cpp file?

Tags: c++, namespaces

It's said that there is only one unique unnamed name in on translation unit. However, bellowing lines still compile.

```
//test.cpp
namespace xxx{
namespace {
int x = 0;
}
}
namespace yyy{
namespace {
int x = 0;
}
}
```

I had a guess that code in nested unnamed namespace was as if the code in the parent namespace, and nested unnamed namespace makes no sense. Didn't know right or not.

Comment: They can exist since they are wrapped around by another unique namespace

Answer (score 2):

Unnamed namespaces are unique to their scope. For example

```
namespace named {
namespace {
int x = 0;
}
namespace {
int x = 0;
}
}
```

would result in an error. The same would apply for the global scope.

With the case you provided, the unnamed namespaces in `xxx` and `yyy` are unique to their respective scopes, therefore there is no name clash.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for the anonymous namespace are different from what you expect. 
 According to the C++ standard / [namespace.unnamed]:

> An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by
>
> ```
> inline namespace unique { /* empty body */ } 
> using namespace unique ;
> namespace unique { namespace-body }
> ```
>
> where `inline` appears if and only if it appears in the
>   unnamed-namespace-definition and **all occurrences of *`unique`* in a
>   translation unit** are replaced by ***the same identifier***, and this
>   identifier differs from all other identifiers in the translation unit.

As a consequence, you code is valid,  since you define `x` each time in a nested anonymous namespace of a different enclosing namespace ( if `uuuu` would be the hypothetical unique identifier mentioned in the standard, it would be `xxx::uuuu` and `yyy::uuuu`).

**Important remark:** the fact that every anonymous namespace behave as if they would have the same identifier that is unique per compilation unit allows to continue a nested namespace:

```
namespace xxx {
    namespace {
        int x = 20;
    }
}
namespace test {
    int x=30;     // no problem: it's a different namespace
}
namespace xxx {
    namespace {
        // int x;     --> forbiden because it's the same nested anonyous space than above  
        int y = x;    // refers to the already defined xxx::{anonymous}::x
    }
}
int main() {
    cout << xxx::y<<endl;    // output is 20 and xxx::y is inaccessible from other compilation units
    return 0;
}
```